# Firestore: storing data to fields with parameter names

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way with Firebase to set a variable as field name with Cloud Firestore?

Example, I would like to have my data stored as such, with just one function:

```
Madonna: true

Queen: false

MJackson: true
```

The function below does not work, but illustrates what I am trying to achieve:

```
  setFavorite(
    channelID: string,
    favorite: boolean
  ): Promise<void> {
      return this.fireStore.firestore.doc(`favorites/${mycustomID}`)
  .set({
      `${channelID}`: favorite
   });
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [square brackets notation](https://medium.com/@prufrock123/js-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-797c4e34f01d), as follows:

```
setFavorite(
   channelID: string, 
   favorite: boolean 
): Promise<void> { 
   let dataObj = {}; 
   dataObj[channelID] = favorite; 
   return this.fireStore.firestore
    .doc(favorites/${mycustomID})
    .set(dataObj); 
}
```

Comment: With this approach, "dataObj" appears in the database as the field name, and it stores the values as a map. What I am hoping to achieve, is to have each paramater as the field name, and directly assigned to it, the boolean value.

Comment: Can you retry, there was a typo in my answer: I copied/pasted your code and forgot to remove the curly brackets.

Comment: Thanks, indeed that works now. Small modification still, and there no need to hard-code the parameter values:

`setFavorite(
    channelID: string,
    favorite: boolean
  ): Promise<void> {
    let dataObj = {};
    dataObj[channelID] = favorite;
    return this.fireStore.firestore.doc(`favorites/${mycustomID}`).set(dataObj);
  }`

Comment: Happy that I could help. Of course you should build the object dynamically and not hardcode the “key” values. It was done like that in the answer to illustrate the method.

Comment: @ElFred I have updated the answer according to your come to. Thanks to approve and upvote the answer.